# How can I still get accurate time in all users even in the device current time uses is not accurate?

Tags: time, flutter

I tried to make a real time database and I want to sort the data according to the time when he sent the data to the server. but if the user does not have the right time eating the sort order the list also becomes incorrect. how do I handle this so that the user before sending data to the server sends the right time not to follow the time on the device? I use DateTime.now () to send data to Firestore. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try sending api request for current time, if you are not dealing with something very sensitive.

I found this [api](http://worldtimeapi.org/).

Comment: Thanks for responding to my question. I will try your advice